# Passing parameters to the constructor of a class through MvvmCross's IoC

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I have an MvvmCross project in which I have defined a `Database` class (implementing a `IDatabase` "service"). This class needs a parameter (the connection string) in the constructor.

Of course, the parameter is known at the level of the application project (WPF, in my case), and not at the level of the library implementing the `Database` class.

My problem is: how do I pass the parameter when the `Database` object is created via the IoC container?

I think I should do something similar to

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IDatabase>(() => new Database("my connection string"));
```

but I can't find out the right place to write this call. The `App` class in the top-level WPF project is in no way related to the `App` class of the "Core" project, so I can't leverage abstract inheritance either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out. The line I wrote in the question was in fact right:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IDatabase>(() => new Database("my connection string"));
```

What I was missing was where to put that line. The correct place is in a `MySetup` class, at the application level, that extends `MvxWpfSetup<MyApp>` - precisely, in the `InitializeLastChance()` method, that gets called *after* the `Initialize()` method of your App class (`MyApp`, as I called it before).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in 6.1. Also see: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/2814

```
var title = "The title";
var subtitle = "The subtitle";
var description = "The description";

var arguments = new { title, subtitle, description };
var d = Mvx.IoCConstruct<Database>(arguments);
```

Comment: Was this introduced in 6.1? There is no way to do it in 6.0.1?!

Comment: I upgraded to 6.1.1, and I see the overload you point out. However, I don't think that's what I need yet. The Database is injected into a ModelView by MvvmCross's reflection. I would need to pass that parameter when that happens - not because I create it explicitly. I need something more like "when you construct an IDatabase, do it using this as the parameter".